# SQLAlchemy, polymorphic inheritance with classical mapping

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to use the classical mapping instead of the declarative, for the last two days I am trying to make inheritance work, I tried with the declarative style and it worked but whatever I tried I cant get it to work when using the old mapping style.

```
class Item(object):

    def specialised_method(self):
        return "I am not special"


class SpecialisedItem(Item):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'special',
    }

    def specialised_method(self):
        return "I am special"

orm.mapper(Item, enviroment.tables.items,
           polymorphic_on=enviroment.tables.items.c.type,
           polymorphic_identity="normal")


# orm.mapper(SpecialisedItem, enviroment.tables.items,polymorphic_on=enviroment.tables.items.c.type,polymorphic_identity='special')

def test_inheritance(request):
    enviroment=get_enviroment()
    session=enviroment.session
    for item in session.query(Item).filter_by(type="special"):
        print(item.type,item.specialised_method(),item)
```

throws:

```
AssertionError: No such polymorphic_identity 'special' is defined
```

If I remove the polymorphic_identity="normal" from the Item mapper_args then the Item's special method gets called, It seems that the SpecialisedItem never gets considered as a child of Item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is probably that you have not passed the inheritance information to `mapper`.  When using classical mapping, the inheritance structure **is not inferred**.

Try something like:

```
class Item(object):
    def specialised_method(self):
        return "I am not special"

class SpecialisedItem(Item):
    def specialised_method(self):
        return "I am special"

orm.mapper(Item, enviroment.tables.items,
           polymorphic_on=enviroment.tables.items.c.type,
           polymorphic_identity="normal")

orm.mapper(SpecialisedItem,
           enviroment.tables.items,

           # you need to specify the parent
           inherits=Item,
           polymorphic_identity='special')
```

Note that there is no need to specify `polymorphic_on` in the mapping for `SpecialisedItem`.  Generally, it will be inferred if there is an appropriate foreign key between the underlying tables, and here you are using the same underlying table so the point is mout.

Comment: Thank you... It's probably my documentation reading skills but I think sqlalchemy lacks documentation for when using the non declarative style. Your code works.